# Change root element of App.config for .net application

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

The standard starting block for App.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
```

Is it possible to change "configuration" to other string value like "StartingConfiguration"

Comment: Specific reason for doing so? You can have 'StartingConfiguration' as a  sectionGroup. Also to be a valid XML root node is required, if you make 'StartingConfiguration' as root node and end the file with same. I don't think that's what you would want.

Comment: Actually we were thinking to use "Configuration" as tag inside another element of which "StartingConfiguration" (root element) could be the parent.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Whether it's advisable is another question entirely. Perhaps if you provided more context...

Comment: I am not asking if it is advisable or not. Its a requirement.

Comment: Have you tried this thing first? If yes and did not work then makes sense to discuss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the root element of app.config because

> The application config file is shared with CLR and Windows SxS. SxS
>   dictates that the root element is , and it should be
>   without namespace.

Source - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2008/03/24/app-configs-root-element-should-be-namespace-less/

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Sections starting with "config" are reserved. You can't name a `ConfigurationSection` "configuration."